# input type number, accepts number only not letter jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

```
$("#number").bind('keyup change click', function() {
            if ($(this).val().match(/^\d+$/)) {

            } else {
                alert("Not a number");
            }
```

This is my code for getting input that is number only from user. It is ok but I got some problem with the `start of click`; when I click it will `alert` that it is not a number even if it is still `empty` so i added another code:

```
if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
}
```

from the start of the the code. It did fix the problem with empty or starting click the problem is when I type in `letters` it `does not alert` the message anymore. How to fix this one?any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Why `===` not `==` ?

Comment: because it has a warning `Expected "===" and instead saw "==". ` I am working in netbeans so i got rid of the warning

Comment: Why you listen `click` event?

Comment: Using `===` is typically good practice due to the way JavaScript handles type conversion when you use `==`. For example, `0 == ''`, but `'' != 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rias has the answer above, but, you could also do the following.

```
$("#number").bind('keyup change click', function() {
    //Check only if the text box is not empty
    if ( $.trim($(this).val()) != "") {
        if ($(this).val().match(/^\d+$/)) {
        } else {
            alert("Not a number");
        }
    }
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/dnfygrk1/)

**Update:** In case you wanted to remove any the non-number characters, try the following.

```
$("#number").bind('keyup change click', function() {

    if ( $.trim($(this).val()) != "") {
        if ($(this).val().match(/^\d+$/)) {
        } else {
            alert("Not a number");
            $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]+/gi, "") );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: even if i write letter no alert

Comment: Check the demo in my answer now.

Comment: You should delete the last entered key if it is not a number, else if you type "a" and then 1 it will still tell you that it is not a number, because it matches the "a".

Comment: @briosheje it wouldn't matter since i only want numbers so having `a` in front of `1` still matches my need to not type in letter.

Comment: @HogRider: you didn't get what I meant: if you write "a" and then 1 it will alert, despite you wrote a number. It would be better, in my opinion, to force the user to be **unable** to write a letter, you just need to add a substring on the input, that's not a huge deal.

Comment: @briosheje ok i understand now so you mean before hand i wont allow user to type letters?so you are telling me from `keystroke` when letter dont allow and if number allow?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dnfygrk1/1/ just this. So that if I type "1" and then "2" and then "a" it will tell me that it is not a number and will REMOVE it keeping 1 and 2 allowing me to write more numbers.

Comment: @briosheje that fails if you are a fast typer!

Comment: @LShetty: You have to be fast though. Not everyone will try to break this and this wasn't a complaint anyway, just wanted to increase the quality of an already good answer. It is still better than not allowing the user to write at all! ;)

Comment: @HogRider: LShetty's answer is already good enough, This is the correct answer and he was the fastest one. I didn't write what he did by my own, just added that little piece of code after the alert, therefore you should accept his answer :)

Comment: ok @briosheje but i really appreciate the good idea on `keystroke`

Comment: @briosheje and LShetty last question what event can be called when i put  value to the input text from database?

Comment: @HogRider: None, unless you're either getting or setting that value through an AJAX request.

Comment: @briosheje yes from ajax i think i will stick to manually calling the `.change` from ajax

Comment: @HogRider: When an ajax request has been completed, you can detect that through the `success` function. In that function you can, therfore, parse the value of the database inside the input and know that you did it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the regular expression to `/^\d*$/` and it will accept an empty field also, because the quantifier `*` accepts 0 or more characters of the type `\d` number, whereas `+` needs 1 or more numbers to match.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#number").bind('keyup change click', function() {
    if ($(this).val().match(/^\d*$/)) {

    } else {
      alert("Not a number");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="number">
```

Comment: this's not good, I type multiple words and get multiple error, and everytime I focus on the input, the alert show.

Comment: I just adjusted the initial code. You might have to put some thinking in it yourself.

Comment: Also it depends what you do, if theres not a number, you could delete the field or the last word or whatever. of course an alert is disturbing and should nit be in a final implementation, but was asked for.